HAProxy terminates / resets an idle connection even there are no timeouts configured
I'm about to test PostgreSQL connection idling over HAProxy. I let a JDBC connection idle in a loop to test this. With each iteration I am doubling the idle wait time.
Currently HAProxy terminates the connection after a 4096 minute idle wait although no timeouts are configured in the "haproxy.cfg". Afaik, all timeouts should be unlimited by default then.
Does anyone have any idea why this happens?



